# Where is the wpa_supplicant.conf option "update_config=1" documented?

Tags: wifi, configuration, documentation

First of all, I know what the option does. According to the Arch Linux Wiki, it gives the command line "wpa_cli" utility the permission to [rewrite](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant) wpa_supplicant.conf:

> Warning: Setting update_config to 1 allows wpa_supplicant to overwrite
> the configuration file. When overwriting, wpa_supplicant will reset
> file permissions according to your default umask. It might
> accidentally make the file readable to everyone thus exposing your
> passwords, if your system is multiuser.

But the Arch Linux wiki is the closest I could get to an authoritative description of this feature. It doesn't appear in any of the man pages for [wpa_supplicant](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/wpasupplicant/index.html), including the following: wpa_cli(8), wpa_supplicant(8) and wpa_supplicant.conf(5).

Where is the official documentation for this feature? My fear is that, if it's indeed an "undocumented" feature that appears only in the source code, then any developer could simply edit out or disable the feature in a future release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option appears to be documented in the [example configuration file](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) on the [project's web site](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/):

```
# Whether to allow wpa_supplicant to update (overwrite) configuration
#
# This option can be used to allow wpa_supplicant to overwrite configuration
# file whenever configuration is changed (e.g., new network block is added with
# wpa_cli or wpa_gui, or a password is changed). This is required for
# wpa_cli/wpa_gui to be able to store the configuration changes permanently.
# Please note that overwriting configuration file will remove the comments from
# it.
#update_config=1
```

As it's documented on the project's web site, I'd assume that the option isn't going anywhere for a while.

Comment: Your gave me the idea to search whether the example config had also been installed as part of my distro's wpasuppllicant package documentation, and indeed it was in /usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/examples/wpa_supplicant.conf (Debian). It just reminded me that not all docs could be read as man or info pages.